# remove item not working in cart codeigniter and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, shopping-cart

I have problem like below, i create with codeigniter in backend and with angular for calculation in front end, my problem is remove itam is not working, and function setTotal not work..

for detail code, like this

```html
<tr ng-repeat = "cart in carts.data">
  <td>{{cart.product_name}}</td>
  <td>{{cart.product_price}}</td>
  <td>{{cart.product_quantity}}</td>
  <td>{{cart.product_quantity * cart.product_price | rupiah}}</td>
  <td><button type="button" name="remove_product" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="removeItem(cart.product_id)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></td>
</tr>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('api', []);

  app.controller('harga', function ($scope, $http){

    $scope.carts = []; 
    $scope.fetchCart = function(){
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>shop/fetch_cart'
      }).then(function (data){
        $scope.carts = data;
      },function (error){
        alert('salah');
      });
    };
    
    $scope.setTotals = function(){
      var total = 0;
      for(var count = 0; count < $scope.carts.length; count++){
        var item = $scope.carts[count];
        total = total + (item.product_quantity * item.product_price);
      }
      return total;
    };

    $scope.removeItem = function(product_id){
      $http({
        method:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>shop/remove_item",
        data:product_id
      }).then(function(data){
        $scope.fetchCart();
      });
    };

  })

</script>
```

buttom delete item not repons

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Do you get any error?

Comment: no error message.

Comment: my problem, when i click remove button, item not deleted

Comment: do you refresh the page the item is removed or not ?